# A problem on FIR filter design given a difference equation

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, filter-design, finite-impulse-response

> Given the following difference equation:
> \begin{equation}
> y(n)=2x(n-2)+3x(n-5)
> \end{equation}
> describing the structure of an FIR filter, design the direct form of one. What is the order of the filter?

The thing is that, do I count the zeroes inbetween in my direct form? Like this? $y(n)=0x(n)+0x(n-1)+2x(n-2)+0x(n-3)+0x(n-4)+3x(n-5)?$ and the filter is of 5th order?

But what if I don't take the zeroes into account and just put different delays in the block diagrams? For instance, I don't have to use a unit delay, right? I could just place $z^{-2}$ and then another $z^{-3}$ as operators. But then would the filter be of 5th order or of 1st order? My professor takes the first answer as correct. However, I can't help but be unsettled and unsatisfied by it.

Answer (score 2):

The filter order is the minimum number of (unit) delay elements necessary to implement the filter, or, equivalently, the order of the corresponding transfer function. In the case of causal FIR filters, this is simply the order of the polynomial describing the transfer function. Consequently, the order of the given FIR filter is $5$.

Note that this doesn't say anything about the actual number of multiplications and additions necessary to implement the filter.

Comment: Well, a slight mathematical comment: The transfer function won't be represented by a polynomial as it will have negative exponents (in thiscase it will be $H(z)=2z^{-2}+3z^{-5}$), but it is really seen as a rational function $\frac{2z^3+3}{z^5}$. There are Laurent Polynomials, but these have to do with Hopf Algebras and are out of the scope of the question.

Comment: @PeterAllen: Technically you're correct. However, the transfer function of a FIR filter can be written as $z^{-N}P(z)$ with a polynomial $P(z)$ (with only positive powers). And it is $P(z)$ that determines all properties of the FIR filter, apart from the bulk delay. For that reason it is common in signal processing to call a FIR transfer function a "polynomial transfer function". This is relevant because we can use polynomial approximation algorithms for FIR filter design, and we don't need to resort to rational approximation, as is the case with IIR filters.

Comment: Got it. Just to avoid any confusion of OP.